# Разный остаток от деления в php и MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Переношу часть функционала из MySQL в php

В одной хранимой процедуре есть участок кода

```
SELECT MOD(992782841398,899981);
```

будет 300583

Аналог в php:

```
print 992782841398 % 899981
```

будет 109645

Подскажите как выкрутится?

Comment: на ideone результат как у вас, а у меня 

    php -r 'echo (992782841398 % 899981)."\n";'
    300583

дело или в том что у меня PHP 5.5.0-6 
или архитектура x86_64

Comment: в архитектуре дело.

Comment: @KoVadim сомневаюсь на счёт архитектуры, т.к. при i686 MySQL на локальном даёт верный результат

Comment: в пхп + архитектура. А мускуль просто понимает, что число большое и обрабатывает корректно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выкинуть php. мускуль правду пишет.

А по факту - у Вас число больше 32бит. Используйте 64битные целые.

php увидел большое число и заменил его на 2147483647.

Детали [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.integer.php).